# Using CoreData for two types of data

Tags: core-data

I have to use CoreData based database to store my data. At high-level my data is divided into 2 sections

a) This type of data changes frequently as user uses the application on regular basis

b) This type of data changes only say once in a day

These databases can have different requirements of versioning and refreshing rates etc.

To store these two types of data, should I use two separate CoreData databases (hence two separate NSManagedObjectContext) OR should I use single database and keep them in separate tables. What are the pros and cons and what are the suggested mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single database with two separate entities because its easier and is a standard way to do it.